# Is there a R function to perform an Ancova post-hoc test to check homogeneity of regression slopes

Tags: r, linear-regression, posthoc, ancova

After adjust some linear models I want, first, to test for homogeneity of regression slopes. The second step, and here is my doubt, I want to employ a post-hoc test to compare **slopes** two by two.

Here goes an example modified from https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/ancova-in-r/

*get data*

```
data("anxiety", package = "datarium")
anxiety <- anxiety[,c("id","group","t1","t3")]
names(anxiety)[c(3,4)] <- c("pretest","posttest")
```

*plot regression lines*

```
ggscatter(anxiety,x="pretest",y="posttest",color="group",add="reg.line")+
    stat_regline_equation(aes(label=paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~"),color = group))
```

*check homogeneity of regression slopes*

```
anova_test(anxiety,posttest~group*pretest)
```

Here we can see a not statistically significant p-value of 4.15e-01

The post-hoc test emmeans_test perform pairwise comparisons to identify which **groups** are different. Nevertheless I want to employ a multiple-comparison procedure to determine which *B*'s (**slopes**) are different from which others.

Is there a function for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are probably many functions that could address this question, but should we give you this knowledge? (Asaking for package recommendations is OT on SO.) That's a pretty borderline p-value. Is there anything that should make us think this was a likely event? It seems quite possible that no pairwise comparison would be significant at the 0.05 level.

Comment: Thank you for your IRTFM comments. There should be a "not" before "statistically significant p-value". I edited the text. The data set was used as a reproducible example. Below, in the answer section, I posted an example where the difference between the slopes is significant. Moreover, about your comment, I think that knowledge is not given, it is shared. If someone has doubts about whether or not to share knowledge, it may be better not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and search more I prepared an example of the analysis I was trying to do. I hope it is useful.
An important source was https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html

```
## packages
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(emmeans)
library(data.table)

## prepare the example data
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(321)

a1 <- 0
b1 <- 1
a2 <- 1
b2 <- 1.7

x <- c(1:10)
y1 <- (a1+b1*x)+rnorm(10,0,.6)
y2 <- (a1+b1*x)+rnorm(10,0,.6)
y3 <- (a2+b1*x)+rnorm(10,0,.6)
y4 <- (a2+b2*x)+rnorm(10,0,.6)

dat <- data.frame(x=rep(x,4),y=c(y1,y2,y3,y4),group=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=10))

## regression and coefficients
lm.dat <- lm(y~x*group,dat)
summary(lm.dat)

## coeficients, confidence intervals and R2 by group
as.data.table(dat)[,as.list(coef(lm(y~x))),by=group]
as.data.table(dat)[,as.list(confint(lm(y~x))),by=group]
as.data.table(dat)[,list(r2=summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared),by=group]

## plots
emmip(lm.dat,group~x,cov.reduce=range)
ggscatter(dat,x="x",y="y",color="group",add="reg.line")+
    stat_regline_equation(aes(label=paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~"),color = group))

## anova
anova(lm.dat)
anova_test(dat,y~x*group)

## interactions with covariates
## slopes for each group and pairwise comparisons
emtrends(lm.dat,pairwise~group,var="x")
```

Comment: The package that I was thinking about when you asked the question was "multcomp" which has a function `glht`, an initialism of "general linear hypothesis test". It allows one to specify tests beyond the default ones you get from `summary.lm`. The problem with answering questions about "how to get the p-value for some particular ad-hoc hypothesis on SO" is that one rarely knows the level of sophistication of the questioner. I wish there were a way that such questions could be shunted through or statistically screened on CrossValidated.com.